# Непонятный вывод в С++?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Есть следующий фрагмент кода программы:
[main.cpp](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtncDbaV4Owk-S6F9u94cwOf6oPX)

Первые 83 человека выводятся нормально, а дальше идут инопланетные слова. Подскажите, где в коде ошибка, и как ее исправить?

Среда разработки CodeBlocks, MinGV

[image: Странные символы]

Comment: Скорее всего читаете за пределами структуры. На этом ресурсе принято всю релевантную информацию включать в тело вопроса, ссылка протухнет и вопрос станет бесполезным.

Comment: Ссылка уже битая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а где return в  функции `Abiturient * generateAbiturients()`
?

У вас вот тут :

```
Abiturient * abiturients = generateAbiturients();
```

возвращается непонятно что, а не ссылка на масси,в которую вы ожидаете.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось(